# Missing Fields on Create stage of the Dynamics CRM Plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is there a way to access empty fields of a Target entity in the preoperation stage when it has not been populated by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.
Target only contains attributes whose values were changed or deleted.
Images only contain attributes that were chosen in Plugin Registration Tool. But they still do not contain attributes with NULL values.
If you tell us more about your development, maybe we could suggest something else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am writing an auto-number plugin. I want to check whether the attribute on the Target entity exists or not and compare it with the attribute the user entered in the auto number main form as the target entity attribute. Then trigger my plugin to populate that field if exits. 
@Dmitri

Answer (score 1):

You can access field by `Entity.Contains()` and `Entity.GetAttributeValue<T>()`. If field has not been populated, `Entity.Contains()` will return a `false` and `Entity.GetAttributeValue<T>()` will return a `default(T)`.

Example:

```
// Entity.Contains(), use this to judge if entity contains a certains field.
if (targetEntity.Contains("yourfiledname"))
{
    var field = targetEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("yourfiledname");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(field))
    {
        // do your logic
    }
}
// Entity.GetAttributeValue<T>() this return a T or default(T).
var optionsetField = targetEntity.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("someoptionsetfield");
if (optionsetField != null)
{
    // do your logic
}
```